# MS AdaptiveCard Issue: Placeholder and the grid cannot be displayed correctly

Tags: grid, size, botframework, placeholder, adaptive-cards

**These two questions are all about the AdaptiveCard Botframework.**

**Q1:** I have set the default *placeholder* value in the **adaptivecard** :**text1**, but after triggering the event, the placeholder cannot be displayed correctly , the *placeholder* was blank. There is no hint information(**text1**) in the placeholder. And even I copied the MS sample code to my source, it still not working. I have tried in the Chrome the Firefox and also in IE11, but all failed.
[The placeholder was blank](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pHvn8.jpg)
[MS samplecode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nHtOe.jpg)
[MS sample linkage](http://adaptivecards.io/explorer/Input.Number.html)
**Q2:** I have set the width for two columns in the columnset using the **adaptivecard**(one was set as **40** and another one was set as **10**), but it seems not working. The *grid* was not displayed correctly.
[My source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6p58K.jpg)
[Width limit seems not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T5koM.jpg)

```
[
        {
          "contentType": "application/vnd.microsoft.card.adaptive",
          "content": {
            "type": "AdaptiveCard",
            "version": "1.0",
            "body": [
              {
                "type": "TextBlock",
                "text": "Test",
                "weight": "bolder",
                "size": "medium"
              },
              {
                "type": "ColumnSet",
                "spacing": "none",
                "columns": [
                  {
                    "type": "Column",
                    "width": 40,
                    "items": [
                      {
                        "type": "Input.ChoiceSet",
                        "id": "country",
                        "style": "compact",
                        "placeholder": "Country",
                        "value": "1",
                        "choices": [

                          {
                            "title": "UnitedStates",
                            "value": "US"
                          }
                        ]
                      }
                    ]
                  },
                  {
                    "type": "Column",
                    "width": 10,
                    "items": [
                      {
                        "type": "Input.Number",
                        "placeholder": "text1",
                        "min": 0,
                        "id": "Text1"
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              }
            ],
            "actions": [
              {
                  "type": "Action.Submit",
                  "title": "Button"            
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
```

Comment: In which channel are you having those results?

Comment: Placeholder in the visualizer seems to function as expected: https://imgur.com/a/MNC3L Which version of the Adaptive Cards library are you using client side?  Is the bot built using node, or .net sdk?

Answer (score 0):

Q1:
The placeholder value is rendered depending on the host renderer. What you can see in this image, is a comparison of several different hosts, and you can see that two of them do render the placeholder.

[image]

Q2:
The columns are correctly set and the columnset does render correctly.

[image]

What you can see here is that columns width in numeric format is a % of overall width, after auto and stretch column widths have been taken into consideration

In the following, your first column is set to Auto, and the second remains at 10

[image]

The second column takes up the entire space because AUTO brings the first column to the slimmest width it can be rendered at.

Visualisers in different hosts may show this differently, but the certainly are intended to be the same regardless of the host.

Hope this helps.